# Understanding mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In Redux, Suppose I have two different un-connected states in redux

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  navBar: navBarReducer,
  exchange: exchangeReducer
})
```

If I dispatch actions which changes state for `navBar`, would `mapStateToProps` trigger render for `exchange: exchangeReducer` as well?

Comment: tldr; no. mapStateToProps triggers only when changes happen to your selected reducers in mapStateToProps

Comment: Strictly speaking it depends on how you are selecting from the state. If say you are filtering an array from the state using `{something: exchange.something.filter(somePredicate)}` w/o memoization it would rerender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, mapStateToProps is related to the render method and not reducers.
Secondly, change in state from one reducer would update the entire component subscribed to it(Unless you have some conditions to pause rendering).

So to answer your question change in one reducer would only reflect a change in components subscribed to it.